# Creating list of dictionaries from a dictionary using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary of the format:

```
d = {'award1' : { 'nominees': ['name1', 'name2'],
                  'presenters': ['name3', 'name4'],
                  'winner' : 'name1'
                }
     'award2' : { 'nominees': ['name5', 'name6'],
                  'presenters': ['name7', 'name8'],
                  'winner' : 'name6'
                }
    }
```

And I'm trying to create a list of dictionaries that separate the values, i.e., the result should be:

```
my_list = [ { 'award1': ['name1','name2'], 'award2': ['name5','name6'] },
            { 'award1': ['name3','name4'], 'award2': ['name7','name8'] },
            { 'award1': 'name1', 'award2': 'name6' }
          ]
```

Is there a way I can do this with a one-line list comprehension?

What I have tried so far:

```
lst = [{key:val['nominees'], key:val['presenters'], key:val['winner']} for key, val in d.items()]
```

And my code using a normal "for" loop:

```
nominees, winner, presenters = {}, {}, {}
    for key, val in d.items():
        nominees[key] = val['nominees']
        winner[key] = val['winner']
        presenters[key] = val['presenters']
lst = [nominees, winner, presenters]
```

Comment: can you please share what you tried so far for this? And yes, there is a way to achieve it with one list-comprehension. If you can share the code with normal `for`, we'll be more then happy to share the *list comprehension* version. We just need to see your efforts to solve this problem

Comment: Dictionary must have ***unique*** keys..

Comment: @Anonymous updated with my attempt and the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a *list comprehension* + *dictionary comprehension* version of one-liner to achieve this:

```
d = {
    'award1' : { 
        'nominees': ['name1', 'name2'],
        'presenters': ['name3', 'name4'],
        'winner' : 'name1'
     },
     'award2' : {
         'nominees': ['name5', 'name6'],
         'presenters': ['name7', 'name8'],
         'winner' : 'name6'
      }
}

# List of keys to maintain the order of elements in the desired list
nested_keys = ['nominees', 'presenters', 'winner']

# In Python 3.7+: If the insertion order of key in initial dict is same as
#                 order of desired list, we can use this to make it more generic
# nested_keys = list(d.values())[0].keys()

new_list = [{k: d[k][key] for k in d.keys()} for key in nested_keys]
```

where `new_list` will hold:

```
[
    {'award1': ['name1', 'name2'], 'award2': ['name5', 'name6']}, 
    {'award1': ['name3', 'name4'], 'award2': ['name7', 'name8']}, 
    {'award1': 'name1', 'award2': 'name6'}
]
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but I would like to point out for the OP that this performs ~3x slower on my system than the OP's code. 600 nanoseconds vs 1.8 microseconds likely isn't going to a bottleneck. But if performance is a concern, it's worth considering.

Comment: storing `d.keys()` in separate variable will improvise the performance